# Open Policy Agent - check existence of elements in a list

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego, conftest

Just started to deal with [conftest](https://www.conftest.dev/) and [OPA](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/), I'm trying to validate a sample kubernetes deployment manifest to make sure it contains a specific key in a list (i.e. `image` **exists** for all `containers`)

here's a sample input

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: hub.com/img1:tag1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

I thought this policy should check the existence of `image` for all containers:

```
deny[reason] {
    input.kind == "Deployment"
    some i
    not input.spec.template.spec.containers[i].image
    reason := "Container.image not found"
}
```

but `conftest` throws an error complaining `not input.spec.template.spec.containers[i].image` `expression is unsafe`

Any comments/suggestions on how to deal with this case is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure variables in negated expressions (`not ...`) are assigned in another non-negated expression in the rule. For example:

```
deny[reason] {
    input.kind == "Deployment"
    container := input.spec.template.spec.containers[_]
    not container.image
    reason := "Container.image not found"
}
```

In this version, the only variable in the negated expression is `container`. The `container` variable is assigned on the previous line, so the expression is safe.

OPA complains about `not input.spec.template.spec.containers[i].image` because it will search for all variable assignments that make the expressions in the rule *true*. Since the variable `i` is not assigned anywhere else, there would be an *infinite* number of assignments to `i` that satisfy `not input.spec.template.spec.containers[i].image`... e.g., `i = 100`, `i = -1`, `i = "foo"`, etc. Since we want to guarantee that policy execution terminates, OPA rejects the expression.

More information and examples on *safety* here: https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/faq/#safety